# Uploading Build to Heroku too slow

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Took too long to upload the build, does the Free Plan affects the uploading performance?

```
 Uploading XXXXXXX.war
    -----> Packaging application...
           - app: XXXXXX
           - including: webapp-runner.jar
           - including: target/XXXXXXX.war
    -----> Creating build...
           - file: slug.tgz
           - size: 28MB
    -----> Uploading build...
```

Comment: I've upgraded to paid version, it still takes several minutes to upload an app...